# Natbib printing bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using the Natbib package. I am using website citation which is this:

```
@misc{liquidity,
  title = "Liquidity",
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/liquidity.asp}",
  note = "Accessed: 2021-03-17",
}
```

However, when I print biblio with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \bibliographystyle{apalike}
 \bibliography{biblio2.bib}
```

in references it is print with `[liq]` instead of `[1]`:

```
[liq] Liquidity.https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/liquidity.asp. Accessed: 2021-03-17.
```

Is there any way how to fix it, so in the references it will be print with `[1]`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a minimal (non-)working example including your preamble? How the entries of a bibliography are displayed depends on a lot of different things. Hence, it is difficult to help you without having this information.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I updated my post, is it better?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Anyway: You are using `apalike, which is not a numeric style (so no `[1]`) but a author-date style, and since your entry has no author and no date, a part of the label is printed.